# Mongoose .save() doesnt work saving number in object

Tags: mongoose

Im trying to change a number, inside an object, inside an array in a mongodb object. The object itself looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60b7656f93b96504600b3b17"
    },
    "pollData": [{
        "option": "asd",
        "votes": 4
    }, {
        "option": "asd",
        "votes": 8
    }],
    "roomId": "EHAM",
    "pollTitle": "asd",
    "locked": false,
    "__v": 0
}
```

Im trying to change it in my express application. However the .save() function does nothing. Heres my code:

```
 let poll;
        try {
            poll = await Poll.find({roomId: user[0].roomId})
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }

        //add 1 to poll vote
        poll[0].pollData[data.choice].votes = 10
        console.log(poll[0].pollData[data.choice].votes) //this logs 10

        try {
             let test = await poll[0].save()
             console.log("this ran") 
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
```

Comment: rather than using await for save, use callbacks. Save has an error call back and does not throw an error. model.save( err => {}).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently mongoose doesnt like when you change an array directly, or saving a copy to a variable. This workaround worked for me:

```
        Poll.findOne({roomId: user[0].roomId}).then(doc => {
            //generate copy of array           
            let newData = []
            doc.pollData.forEach((item) => {
                newData.push(
                    {option: item.option, value: item.value}
                )
            })


            //this doesnt work:
            //let newData = doc.pollData

            //edit and save value
            newData[data.choice].value += 1
            doc.pollData = newData;
            doc.save();
        })
```